# Question on gradients of the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis

For a differential functions $f: R^n\to R$, we know that the gradient of $f$ on $R^n$ is given by
$$
\nabla f=[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}]^T.
$$

If we consider the gradient of $f$ on the $n$-dimensional sphere $S^{n-1}$, why the gradient of sphere is defined by
$$
\nabla_{S^{n-1}} f:=\nabla f-(\nabla f\cdot x) x
$$
where $x=[x_1,\dots, x_n]^T$.

Comment: $\nabla_{S^{n-1}}f$ is the tangential component of $\nabla f$, and noticed that the normal vector is just $x$.

Comment: @ling Sorry, can you explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about why a certain definition seems useful, so I will provide an example that hopefully illumantes, why it might not be as useful to define $\nabla_{S^{n-1}}f = \nabla f$.

In fact, ask yourself this: Given a function $f$ defined on $S^{n-1}$ how can one compute the gradient? To even differentiate a function $f$ at $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$, the domain of $f$ needs to contain an open subset around $x_0$. But $S^{n-1}\subset \mathbb R^n$ does not contain any open neighborhoods for any of its points. So in order to differentiate $f$, we need to extend $f$ to some open neighborhood of $S^{n-1}$. If we do this, we can compute the ordinary gradient of $f$ at each point in $S^{n-1}$. We might be tempted to say that this is the gradient of the function $f$ on $S^{n-1}$.

But there is one issue here. In order to differentiate $f$, we had to extend $f$ onto some neighborhood. But there might have been different choices of how to do this. Do all these choices yield the same gradient on points in $S^{n-1}$? The answer is no. In fact, let me give an explicit example.

Consider the constant function $f : S^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(s) = 1$. We can extend $f$ in two different ways. The obvious way
$$ f_0 : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R,\quad f_0(x) = 1,$$
as well as
$$f_1 : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R,\quad f_1(x_1, \dots, x_n) = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2.$$
Both functions agree on $S^{n-1}$ with $f$, since $f_1$ is just the square of the Euclidean distance function. The gradient of $f_0$ is $0$ everywhere as $f_0$ is constant. The gradient of $f_1$ however is
$$\nabla f_1(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 2 \cdot (x_1, \dots, x_n)^\top\neq 0$$
for all points in $S^{n-1}$. Therefore, if we wanted to define a gradient-like function on $S^{n-1}$, simply extending any such $f$ and computing the ordinary gradient is not well-defined.

Here, the tangential space comes into play. Let $T_pS^{n-1}$ be the set of velocity vectors $c'(0)$ of curves $c : (-1, 1) \to S^{n-1}$ with $c(0) = p$. We call this the tangent space of $S^{n-1}$. It is in fact a vector space and one can show that for $p = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^\top$ this tangent space is the following:
$$T_pS^{n-1} = \langle (x_1, \dots, x_n)^\top\rangle^\bot,$$
that is the orthogonal complement of $p$.

With a bit of effort, one can now establish, that given two extensions $f_0$ and $f_1$ of $f$ defined on $S^{n-1}$, their gradients might be different (see above), but for any point $p\in S^{n-1}$ the difference $\nabla f_0(p) - \nabla f_1(p)$ is orthogonal to the tangent space $T_pS^{n-1}$. Again, look at our previous example. There the difference of gradients $\nabla f_0(x) - \nabla f_1(x) = -\nabla f_1(x) = -2(x_1, \dots, x_n)^\top \in (T_xS^{n-1})^\bot$.

I.e. if we only consider the orthogonal projection of $\nabla f_i$ to the tangent space, then those two gradients agree. Hence, we have a well-defined gradient for functions $f$ on $S^{n-1}$, by choosing any extension $f_0$ of $f$ and setting

$$\nabla_{S^{n-1}}f (p)= \pi_{T_pS^{n-1}}(\nabla_{\mathbb R} f_0(p)),$$
where $\pi_{T_pS^{n-1}}$ denotes the orthogonal projection. But we can explicitly compute $\pi_{T_pS^{n-1}}$, as we know $T_pS^{n-1}$, this gives exactly your formula $\nabla_{S^{n-1}}f(x) = \nabla f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), x\rangle \cdot x$.

This general approach even works for any submanifold $M$ of Euclidean space, not only for $S^1$.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask which textbook I can find this formula in? This formula is the definition, right?

Comment: I think, any book dealing with submanifolds will have a definition along those lines, but I do not know a particular one of hand, I’m afraid.

Comment: It is a very nice explanation!